# How to create a search function within Excel

Tags: excel, search, lookup

Could somebody please help me create a search feature in Excel, intended as a contact lookup? I'm reasonably comfortable in Excel up to 2016 but have no VBA knowledge so I hope this can be done without it. Using Excel 365 and it will be published to Sharepoint to specific users. I know it's poor practice on here to rely on sample data so I'll do my best to explain with a couple of screenshots.

**Situation:**
I have a raw data sheet containing 50,000 rows (CustomerName, ID, City, Country, EmailAddress etc). Our sales team need to look up contact details but *only* if they know the customer's name, or part thereof.
I need to hide the underlying data but a rudimentary system is acceptable, we just don't want to serve it up on a platter. The basic shove-it-under-the-mattress method by making it all white text; lock all cells; hide all rows and columns; password protect and hide the sheet is fine for now - no one will be determined enough to start picking that apart.

I've searched here and while there are *similar* results, nothing really fits perfectly. The most suitable so far was on extendoffice which doesn't *quite* suffice (will put link in attachment). It utilises SEARCH, RANK, ROW and VLOOKUP functions, the interaction of which I don't entirely understand, but it works.

[Interim steps for the lookup function on sheet "Search"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbSGd.png)

**Issues with current concept:**

- There's no discernable order to the results. The RANK and ROW functions seem to randomly assign ranks, and when you get 50+ results with no way of sorting it will be frustrating.
- Whenever one person queries it undoes the last person's search. Expected, but not nice

[Partial string search with results unsorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh6o3.png)

**Additionally:**

- This doc will be on Sharepoint, directly accessible by ~20 people. Ideally, when one person searches it won't change on someone else's screen
- Results should appear alphabetically by customer name

**Nice to haves:**

- Add another criteria to search by. Eg City or Account Manager - doesn't have to stack
- Select and copy the contents of a cell (eg email address), but not allow editing of the value or formula. If not possible I'll leave the cells completely locked as the trade-off of accidentally overriding a formula is not worth it.

Any help would be super appreciated

Comment: So, did you edit the one you found?

Comment: @SolarMike Edit what? I've tried rejigging the staging formulas but always ended in errors; hence my post here.